# JavaScript printing multiple times

Tags: javascript, arrays, printing

hello i am trying to get the user to input a few marks and the at the end give the highest mark and the lowest mark but for some reason it prints the twice and on the second time it prints infinity and ideas?

```
    var gradeAwarded;
var gradeAwarded;
var repeate = true;
var max;
var A;
var B;
var C;
var F;

var repeat, studentArr = [], markArr = [];
while (repeat !== 'n' && repeat !== 'N'){
    studentArr.push(prompt("Enter Student Name: "));
    markArr.push(parseInt (prompt("Enter Student mark: ")));
    repeat = prompt ("Do you want to enter another student: y/n");
}  

Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(Math, markArr);
};

Array.prototype.min = function() {
  return Math.min.apply(Math, markArr);
};
var min = markArr.min();
var max = markArr.max();


if (markArr <0 || markArr >100){
    alert("Grate out of bounds");
}else if (markArr >= 83){
    gradeAwarded = "A";
    A = +1;
}else if (markArr >= 70){
    gradeAwarded = "B";
    B = +1;
}else if (markArr >= 50){
    gradeAwarded = "C";
    C = +1; 
}else if (markArr >= 0){
    gradeAwarded = "F";
    F = +1;                                                     
}

    document.write("The Highest mark was : "+max);
    document.write("The Lowest mark was : "+min);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be || instead of &&

```
while (repeat !== 'n' || repeat !== 'N'){
    studentArr.push(prompt("Enter Student Name: "));
    markArr.push(parseInt (prompt("Enter Student mark: ")));
    repeat = prompt ("Do you want to enter another student: y/n");
}
```

and also you should **clear** or set **null** to **repeat** variable at the and of process

Comment: you are right it should be || but for some reson it makes an infenite loop

Comment: Hello i want to display my data like so 
Student                    Mark                                   Grade
Student                    Mark                                   Grade
Student                    Mark                                   Grade
Student                    Mark                                   Grade
Student                    Mark                                   Grade

how would i go about this here is my code never mind the document.write at the bottom for another part of my assignment.

Comment: Youe question not clear. Please open a net question and explaint it well

Answer (score 1):

you use a while loop so the 2nd time you run the script it never runs because repeat=='n'. The markArry is reset so that is why you get infinity the 2nd time running the script.

you should use a do while loop instead. Something like this:

```
do {
  studentArr.push(prompt("Enter Student Name: "));
  markArr.push(parseInt (prompt("Enter Student mark: ")));
  repeat = prompt ("Do you want to enter another student: y/n");
}while(repeat !=='n' || repeat !=='N');
```

that should work

Comment: I don't think you're posting your entire script